# i try to create dynamic row with text box but not work blur on each text box

Tags: jquery

```
var count = 1;
$("#addproduct").click(function() {
    var addrows = '<tr><td>' + count + '</td><td><select id="product_' + count + '"></select></td><td><input type="text" id="qty_' + count + '" name="qty_' + count + '" /></td>';
    alert("button click ")
    $("#addRow").append(addrows);
});
$(document).on('blur', '#qty_' + count, function() {
    alert("cal  bulur on each text box " + count);
    count = count + 1;
});
```

Comment: can you post the complete code? also try moving the on.blur event inside click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try the below code? After inserting the element into DOM, you have to bind the blur event.

```
var count = 1;
$("#addproduct").click(function() {
    var addrows = '<tr><td>' + count + '</td><td><select id="product_' + count + '"></select></td><td><input type="text" id="qty_' + count + '" name="qty_' + count + '" /></td>';
    $("#addRow").append(addrows);

    $('#qty_' + count).blur(function() {
      alert("cal  bulur on each text box ");
    });
    count = count + 1;
});
```